# x and o in tic tac toe keeps alternating

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-logic

in my tic tac toe game the  x and o's keep alternating no matter where i click on my cell boxes. i tried typing return at the end of the function and it doesnt stop. i know it has something to do with the turn += 1, at the bottom but dont know how to come about it. really appreciate some advice.

```js
let playerOne = 'x';
let playerTwo = 'o';
let turn = 0;
let lastClicked;

const gameBoard = document.querySelector('.gameBoard');

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const gameBox = document.createElement('div');
  gameBox.classList.add('gridCellItem');
  gameBox.id = 'cell' + i;
  gameBox.addEventListener('click', clickGameBox);
  gameBoard.appendChild(gameBox);
}


function clickGameBox(event) {

  if (turn === 0) {
    event.target.innerText = playerOne;
    lastClicked = playerOne;
  } else {
    if (lastClicked === playerOne) {
      event.target.innerText = playerTwo;
      lastClicked = playerTwo;

    } else {
      event.target.innerText = playerOne;
      lastClicked = playerOne;

    }
  }
  turn += 1;

}
```

```html
<div class="gameBoard"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please complete it so it is a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code to see what's happening?

Comment: hi, im new to coding and by "debugger" step do you mean by go through and console.log everything?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you need in functionality. Means you want to return something or stop alternating when all boxes are filled?